# Can I construct dynamically detail content in UI-Accordion-Component at Touch moment?

Tags: codenameone

In my App I need to listening Touch event at a UI-Accordion-Component  and then  request and show details dynamically.  All of that on demand.
Is It possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the API wasn't designed for that.

For most such use cases you can use [Tree](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/tree/Tree.html) which does allow it.

Comment: Thank you Shai for your response and suggestion.